# Can't resize my drive, because there are unmovable files at the end

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, defragment

There are two unmovable files at the end of my partition, which prevents "Disk management" to resize the drive properly.

The files are:
`Syscache.hve.LOG.1`
`Syscache.hve`

There is no shadow copy running, and the System Restore feature is turned off.
Any ideas how could I move these files? (Let MyDefrag defrag them...)

**OS: Windows 7 Professional x64 SP1**

Comment: Apparently native Windows Defrag will move these files. Give that a bash.

Comment: @RandolphWest - Post that as an answer. ("Disk Cleanup" and the native Defrag did the thing. Thank you!)

Comment: I have done as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently native Windows Defrag will move those files for you. Give that a bash.

If that fails, use [GParted Live Disc](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/). That will do the job.
(Remember. Always backup before such a resize. Oh, and "[Pendrive Linux 1 2 3](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)" will help you make a bootable USB drive from the .iso, if that is your wish.)

*Source: http://www.mydefrag.com/forum/index.php?topic=5773.0*

Comment: I gave it a try yesterday, it took hours to defrag. First it seemed the problem is fixed, the mentioned two files have disappeared. Yet, I can't resize my partition. Only 44gb can be chipped off.

Comment: Okay, GParted live cd time!

Comment: In times like this, I use `fsutil` and resize the NTFS journal. Usually that helps.

Comment: GParted fixed it.